# Name for the "space between the sky and the earth"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

What is the correct name for the space between heaven and earth?

I thought of ***ether*** but it seems to have a prevailing chemistry meaning, whereas its second connotation is described by [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=ether%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03yqMxkxulUFHbyrwnYv3JSmmBqlg%3A1623406820365&source=hp&ei=5DjDYJP5E-GAhbIPjp2moAU&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYMNG9O4rkDSElaPI1Rpsv1etmWE68lEb&oq=ether&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIKCAAQhwIQsQMQFDIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDMgUIABCxAzIICAAQsQMQgwEyBQgAELEDMggIABCxAxCDAToHCAAQsQMQQ1DLBFiYCmCaE2gAcAB4AIABf4gBzwSSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=gws-wiz) as literary:

> LITERARY: the clear sky; the upper regions of air beyond the clouds.

Plus, this doesn't seem to include the space below the clouds.

Then I thought of ***atmosphere***, but its main meaning seems to be

> the mixture of gases around the earth ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atmosphere)).

When I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=space%20between%20sky%20and%20earth&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03SMaZOo9qRV7o3T_aT6iNYvgRZdQ%3A1623406824923&ei=6DjDYMnhN8WGjLsPz6-DmAo&oq=space%20between%20sky%20an&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoFCAAQsQM6BQgAEJECOgcIABCxAxBDOggILhCxAxCDAToCCC46CAghEBYQHRAeOgQIABANUOmKDljCvg5ggtAOaAVwAngAgAHPCYgBsx6SAQo0LjE3LjEuNy0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) it, I found the definition of ***horizon*** as

> the apparent boundary between the Earth and sky.

However, I am looking for the word that denotes the *space in between*, not the boundary.

I am making up this sentence:

> She lost sight of the swans that vanished into the _______ .

or

> The boy measured the ________ and wished that one day he could traverse it with a spaceship.

The examples I have given are rather orientative, not restrictive. If the word or phrase found doesn't go well in the senteces but means exactly this space between sky and earth, I'd be happy.

The word or phrase can be figurative, but I could also use a "technical term" for it.

**Edit:** My question is vague. Maybe it helps if I say just ignore the examples. ***Sky*** is too general a word, I would need something more specific, more synonymous of ***troposphere***, without being necessarily a scientific word. If there are other scientific words, I do not reject them either.

Comment: *... vanished into the **haze***?

Comment: Yes, that's also a good one.

Comment: I think the word you want for your sentences is, in fact, *sky.* Why is *sky* not appropriate?

Comment: If sky isn't the term, we need some description of why. "Sky" isn't a scientific term and it refers to anything above your head or above the ground that isn't a ceiling or roof. Since clouds often come down to earth (where they're known as mist or fog), as do other things in the sky, there is no real practical difference between sky and the air around us.

Comment: Indeed. The sky doesn't 'end' somewhere above our heads - the boundary (horizon) only 'exists' where we have an unobstructed view for a long distance to where the sky appears to meet the land or sea.

Comment: @ Stuart I was looking for a more specific word than "sky", if it exists, even a scientific term. It may render the sentence less common.

Comment: There is a problem with your question.  Can you please further clarify?  First of all, Earth is a planet with a surface and an atmosphere.  There is nothing else.  In everyday parlance, however, we distinguish between the (solid) 'ground' or 'earth' and above that is the 'air'.  That is what birds and airborne insects take to when they fly away.  We say they are in the sky when they are even above things that are on the ground (buildings, trees etc.)  But swans do not 'disappear' into it, except when we speak of something as vanishing 'into thin air'.  Perhaps that is the phrase you want.

Comment: @Tuffy Yes, I am trying to pin down something nearer to the more "terminological side" of what we see between earth and what we call the sky or heaven.  I thought "ether" was quite close, as in my mother tongue it is the right term. In English though it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @ fev I am not sure I understand what you mean by  "terminological side".  In what sense is this particular flock of water fowl "vanishing"?  Swans can be seen in flight.   They fly through the air and if, when in flight, they vanish it will only be into the distance or into the clouds.  Heaven, of course, is a speculative location, certainly out of sight (except in ceiling paintings of the 17th and 18th centuries) but hardly what you seem to be talking about.  Do these swans get out of sight for any other reason than that they are too far away or obscured by buildings or trees?

Comment: @Tuffy: As I said in the OP, I made up these sentences not to restrict but just to give a possible use. To be honest, I am in difficulty, because I cannot expose the real context I need it for. By "terminological side" I mean the technical term they use in science. It seems the term is "troposphere". So starting from this point I am looking for a word that is close to troposphere, acurate, without being necessarily scientific. **Yonder blue** is abeautiful metaphore but not very acurate. So is **azure**.

Comment: @fev If you can't say how it's to be used, and you can't say why *sky* is inappropriate (which does follow from the first restriction), then it's going to be difficult to come up with *le mot juste.*

Comment: Could you say that they vanished _towards_ or _into_ the horizon?

Comment: Birds either vanish into the distance or into the clouds/fog/mist/haze/rain or other obscuring weather phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Troposphere**

> the lowest region of the atmosphere, extending from the earth's
> surface to a height of about 6–10 km (the lower boundary of the
> stratosphere)
>
> [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/troposphere)]

but that might be a bit "sciencey" sounding for your suggested sentences.

and interpretative suggestion might be something like:

**Blue yonder**

or similar

Comment: @sawsine: Don't you think _birds vanishing into the troposphere_ is a bit too artsy? _blue yonder_ is a good one! +1 for that :)

Answer (score 4):

The word "*azure*" is a term that is suitable, although it is literary.

> (SOED) **azure** **5** The unclouded vault of the sky.

> (SOED) **vault** **1** *Archit.* A continuous arch, or a series of arches radiating from a central point or line, used to form a roof over a space in the interior of a building; an arched roof or ceiling. ME. **b** An arching structure or covering resembling a vault; *esp.* (more fully *heavenly vault*, vault of heaven*) that formed by the sky (chiefly *poet.*) LME.

Since clouds are well known to have volume, as well as being found over a range of altitudes that can be quite high and quite low, the term "azure" does refer to a space that occupies a fairly important part of what lies between the elusive boundary of blue expanse above our heads and the earth.

([ref., 1995](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/News_from_the_Front/BPAaAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22disappeared+into+the+azure%22&dq=%22disappeared+into+the+azure%22&printsec=frontcover)) Shortly after the third jet had disappeared into the azure, a mortar shell landed on the far side of the airport, well away from any aircraft and apparently causing no damage.

- She lost sight of the swans that vanished into the azure.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think this is a concept that isn't recognized in English. For me, the sky is anywhere I don't see ground or something attached to the ground. I would consider a bird flying a few inches above my head to be "in the sky" (assuming we weren't in some kind of structure). The idea of empty space between the sky and the ground is nonsensical to me. No matter which word or phrase you use, I don't think you will be understood.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **distance.**

> A stretch of space without designation of limit; an expanse.

*a land of few hills and great distances.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

And therefore you could write your sentence thus:

*She lost sight of the swans that vanished into the distance.*

Comment: Would it be too much to ask the downvoter his reason for downvoting?

Comment: It’s not my downvote, but *distance* is too broad. Someone walking down a long road can “vanish into the distance” without taking flight.

Comment: It could be because "into the distance" does not connote three dimensional space but remoteness : (OALD) _in/into the distance_ far away but still able to be seen or heard//That make your sentence illogical. I would make that criticism myself.

Comment: In "a  land of few hills and great distances" it is meant in the AHD "one dimensional space".

Answer (score 1):

**[Stratoshpere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stratosphere)**

1. the part of the earth's atmosphere which extends from the top of the
   troposphere to about 30 miles (50 kilometers) above the surface and
   in which temperature increases gradually to about 32° F (0° C) and
   clouds rarely form
2. a very high or the highest region on or as if on a graded scale

Stratosphere better conveys the idea of being "above the sky" and "almost space", e.g. sometimes the term "[near space](https://www.hobbyspace.com/NearSpace/)" is used in aeronautics, and includes this region.  Plus it has more [metaphorical connotations](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/322994/157202) than the troposphere.